# aws ec2 - when would inbound and outbound rule apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to web/vm hosting.
I am using EC2 to host my server.

What are inbound and outbound mean?
When would inbound and outbound rule apply?

From my understanding, when I want to ssh to my ec2 instance, I need to add an inbound rule allowing my IP to ssh traffic. Are there any use cases inbound rules are applied?

I cannot think of when outbound rules will be used. Is there any examples?

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot think of when outbound rules will be used. Is there any examples?

There are many use-cases:

- you want to access internet from the instance
- your application is using external API
- you want to connect to RDS database from the instance
- and many more

**By default all outbound traffic is allowed**, thus everything works as expected. But sometimes you would like to limit that. A popular case is to allow your instance to interact with a single RDS instance and nothing else.

Comment: what port should I open to connect to RDS database?

Comment: @CCCC By default everything outbound is allowed, so you don't have to worry. Did you change the outbound rules? port depends on your database. Each DB has unique port.

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to **Security Groups**.

A Security Group is a virtual firewall on an Amazon EC2 instance (or, more correctly, an Elastic Network Interface).

If a Security Group does not permit access, then no network traffic will go in/out of the instance.

You should configure **minimum possible rules** for Inbound traffic -- typically port 22 for SSH, 80/443 for HTTP/S, etc.

Normally, you can use the default "Allow All" rule for Outbound traffic, since you can typically trust the apps running on your own instance.

The port required for your database depends on the database engine being used. For example, MySQL uses port 3306, PostgreSQL uses port 5432. Just do a web search to find the port.